# Upper bound for a Fresnel Integral

Tags: integration, integral-inequality

I was wondering if there is an upper bound strictly less than 1 to the function $x \mapsto \int_{0}^{1} \sin (x^2 + t^2) dt$ for $x \in [0,1]$. And if it is how to derive it.

Thank you for your answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a trig identity to write

$$
\sin(x^2+t^2)=\sin(x^2)\cos(t^2)+\sin(t^2) \cos(x^2)
$$

Now you have two Fresnel integrals; S and C, leading to

$$
I(x)=\cos(x^2)\operatorname{S}(1) +\sin(x^2)\operatorname{C}(1)
$$

Over $0 \leq x \leq 1$, this is maximum at $x=1$, so

$$
I_{\text{max}}=I(1)=\cos(1)\operatorname{S}(1) +\sin(1)\operatorname{C}(1) \approx 0.93
$$

Comment: Why is the maximum at $x=1$ ?

Comment: I looked at the graph! If you wanted to prove it, you could take the derivative, show the only zero of $I'$ is at $x=0$ (for real $x$), note that $I'>0$ anywhere within $0<x<1$ (say at $x=1/2$), and conclude that $I$ is increasing everywhere within that domain.